# css: inline-block is helping center the nav bar - need understanding of the working

Tags: css

In the source code below of the example page of this site:

```
 http://6.470.scripts.mit.edu/css_exercises/exercise5.html

<head>
<style>
body
{
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
}
#container
{
    width:1000px;
    background-color:#dddddd;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
#navigation
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top:20px;
}

#navigation_bar
{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:auto;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#navigation_bar li
{
    float:left;
}
#navigation_bar a:link, #navigation_bar a:visited
{
    display:block;
    width:120px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#993738;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <h1 id="big_title">6.470 Web Programming Competition</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul id="navigation_bar">
            <!--On a real website, you would put the URL you want to navigate to inside href-->
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#materials">Materials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#competition">Competition</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pastyears">Past Years</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

The navigation bar is centered only when display: inline-block is used in div#navigation. If it is removed, then the navbar is not centered at all. Even the margin: auto for ul#navigation_bar is not helping. If a width is mentioned for the ul##navigation_bar then it is able to center the navbar. My question is, how is the whole thing working ie how does display:inline-block makes the navbar center and how does the fixed width also make the ul#navigation_bar also work? And how does margin: auto have no effect like in other cases?

Thanks a lot for help clarifying.

Comment: Do you have a demo for this that we can see/play with?

Answer (score 1):

The `<ul>` is a block element and will try to occupy the full width of its container by default.  With `inline-block` on the parent, it only grows to the width of its contents (the `<li>`s) because the contents of an `inline-block` element [are formatted as a block box](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html).  This is affected by the [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting) -- the `<ul>` touches the edges of its container.  If `display: inline-block` is not specified on the `<div>`, it occupies the full width and so does the `<ul>`, and `margin: 0 auto;` has no effect.

Note that you could also put `display: inline-block` on the `<ul>` itself to reduce its width and make `margin: 0 auto` effective.